# Clash of Clans - Can I Choose only 10 Members in a 15+ Member Clan for War?

Tags: clash-of-clans

With the relatively recent updates for Clash of Clans it is possible to select who goes to war.

I currently am in a 10 person clan but would like to grow the clan.

**Can a Co/Leader take only 10 people into the war if there are 15+ people in the clan or are you forced to stick to the nearest multiple of 5?**

I have tried finding the answer to this but to no avail.

The reason I want to do this is because:

1. We would not need a "holiday clan" for people who want to chill for a bit
2. We could have some control over the match ups we have
3. Non participating and bad performing members can be excluded
4. People could be rotated out for wars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you're not limited to the closest multiple of 5.

## So, yes - You can choose to take only 10 people to war, even if you have more than 15 members.

With the update, as many people as possible are allowed to sit out, as long as the total number participating *is* a multiple of 5 and is more than the minimum requirement of 10 participants.

All you have to do is set who to exclude/include.

I'm in a clan of about 48/50 people and only 30 (18 sitting out) of us go to war at the same time.
*The rest are either marked out, unlucky to be left out by trophy ranking cutoffs or marked as away whilst leeching.. Or are marked as in but excluded because they only attack with Barbarians and Archers...*

Comment: You should be kicking players who are attacking with barbs/archers :D

Comment: I know. But I'm not co-leader :/ And we're ironically Level 4... See clan #8VGCUVJ for more details. But fortunately, that number is only 2... Or so.

Comment: Each clan can choose how to select players for inclusion.  We exclude those who made late or no attacks in the last war(s), have had no donations, who recently joined the clan or who appear to be inactive.